# Consecutive Rest request doesn't bring updated data

Tags: c#, .net, rest, zendesk

Working with the [ZenDesk Rest API](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/introduction) (some ticket management software), I have the functionalities of listing tickets and creating new ones.

Here's the scenario:

1. GET tickets;
2. Create a new ticket;
3. GET tickets again (and show them in a grid);

On step one, say 20 tickets are returned. On step 3, the same 20 tickets are returned. After a while though, the request brings the 21 expected tickets.

Here's some code:

```
public JObject GetTicketsByUserEmail(string userEmail)
{
    var client = new RestClient(RequestUri);
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(Username, Password);
    string resource = "/api/v2/search.json?query=type:ticket tags:" + userEmail;
    var request = new RestRequest(resource, Method.GET);
    client.AddDefaultHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.Parameters.Clear();
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    var content = response.Content;

    client.Execute(request);

    JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(content);

    return jObject;
}
```

The above works fine, bringing the tickets as expected. After creating a new one, I can see on ZenDesk's web application the newly created ticket.

The above code is then run again but it doesn't bring the new ticket to the .Net code, despite existing on the ZenDesk portal! So the list that is shown to the user is refreshed but doesn't show him the ticket he just created.

Well, since I can see the new ticket on the ZenDesk portal, I'm guessing the Rest request on the .Net side is somehow not refreshing or using old data, I don't know.

I need to return the new updated data with newly created records in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their support team provided the answer to this.

Since I'm retrieving my tickets using their `Search` method instead of the `Tickets` one (because I want to filter my results), the results retrieved aren't immediately updated, as they alert in their [documentation](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/search):

> Note: It can take up to a few minutes for new tickets, users, and other resources to be indexed for search. If new resources don't appear in your search results, wait a few minutes and try again.

So, after creating a new ticket, it is actually created but not immediately indexed for search, which means a `Search` call that is made right after a ticket creation won't contemplate that new record.

The time that takes to index the new records isn't fixed or possibly calculated.